# Update Query works fine locally but not on Remote server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have update query that works perfectly fine from my local machine..
   However, when i deploy the application on server.. the table does not get updated.
   Can anyone think of a reason for this. Thank You.

Comment: We can't help you without the relevant pieces of code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of potential reasons.

1. You don't have permission on the remote system
2. The Remote system is not set up to accept remote connections - SQL Browser service is a prime culprit
3. You don't have the same protocol(s) set up on both server and client

There are three potential reasons I can come up with in a minute. All of these are easy to Google, as well. And, that may not be the entire list, but I don't have any context. Check and see if you have any error messages, especially those obfuscated with something like this:

```
try
{
    //Do database stuff here
}
catch
{
   //Ignore
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more common problem - "NTLM one hop" - if you using current user's credentials to connect to SQL and SQL is on another box (browser machine -> server machine -> SQL machine) you'll hit it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't update and there are no errors?   [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/10/16/why-sql-updates-fail-three-reasons.aspx) are some reasons.